# Play 3D sound but at full volume

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

In my fist person shooter (unity), I'm using `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint` to indicate an enemy spawn. It's important that the player hears this sound, in 3D, so that he has an indication of where the enemy spawns.
This works fine, but since the enemy is far away, the volume of the sound is very low.

Is there a way to make unity ignore the distance, but keep the 3D sound capacities so that one could still tell whether the enemies spawn behind/above/... them?

I handled this now by reducing the other volumes, for example of the gun firing, to 0.05. But this makes the game overall real quiet, of course.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How about performing `PlayClipAtPoint()` in the direction of the enemy (say, a unit vector from the camera towards the enemy), rather than at the enemy's actual position? This will allow you to have a consistently loud sound play in the appropriate direction.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect solution, however, since I'm rather new to 3D game development, I don't know how to do this exactly... What should I change to `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(spawnSound, targets[i].transform.position);`?

Comment: Give me a moment, and I can write up an answer for how I envision the solution could work.

Comment: Instead of PlayClipAtPoint, you can add an AudioSource to the enemy that plays at start and play with the 3d sound volume curve in the inspector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to play `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint()` in the *direction* of the enemy spawn, but not necessarily at the *position* of it. This way, you can still provide the appropriate auditory cues for the direction in which an enemy spawns, but you can play them at a consistent volume.

The basic approach is to calculate a unit vector between the player and the enemy spawn, then add this vector to the player's position to determine where to play the spawn sound. Here's an idea of how that might look (where `player` is the GameObject containing the camera):

```cs
// First, calculate the direction to the spawn
Vector3 spawnDirection = targets[i].transform.position - player.transform.position;

// Then, normalize it into a unit vector
Vector3 unitSpawnDirection = spawnDirection.normalized;

// Now, we can play the sound in the direction, but not position, of the spawn
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(spawnSound, player.transform.position + unitSpawnDirection);
```

Afterwards, you just need to change the volume of the audio clip you're playing to the level you want it to be at. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks! I have one issue though... `player.transform.position` doesn't seem to update when I move my character. What could be the cause of this? If I put `Debug.Log(player.transform.position)` in the Update function and I move my character, it keeps saying it's at (0,0.3,0). I did it like this: `public GameObject player;`and then I simply dragged my player in the inspector from the hierarchy.

Comment: @binoculars That's odd - are you sure the object you're manipulating is the same one being referenced in code? For example, are you sure you're not moving around a child of the player object?

Comment: You are right, the parent isn't moving, the child is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Drag  an existing AudioSource to the GameObject's position and play it from there, like so:

```
  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
  {
    // Play an AudioSource from the scene at this.GameObject's location: 

    AudioSource audioSource = GameObject.Find("ASExplosion").GetComponent<AudioSource>(); 
    // Move audioSource to location of this.GameObject and play it.  
    audioSource.transform.position = transform.position;
    audioSource.Play(); 
         

    Destroy(this.gameObject);
   
 }
```

Comment: Note that one can set the audio volume curve in the AudioSource: make the distance greater and the drop off less steep to extend the range. Make sure to set "Spatial Blend" to 3D!

Answer (score 0):

As a static function, also according to the maximum distance it applies the sound proportionally.

```
public static void PlaySound(AudioClip clip, Transform collision, Transform player, int DistanceSoundLimit)
{
    float cameraDistance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, collision.position);


    float normalizedValue = Mathf.InverseLerp(0, DistanceSoundLimit, cameraDistance);
    float explosionDistanceVolumen = Mathf.Lerp(1f, 0, normalizedValue);
    // First, calculate the direction to the spawn
    Vector3 spawnDirection = collision.position - player.position;

    // Then, normalize it into a unit vector
    Vector3 unitSpawnDirection = spawnDirection.normalized;

    Debug.Log("Camera distance: " + cameraDistance + " explosion sound volumen : " + explosionDistanceVolumen);
    // Now, we can play the sound in the direction, but not position, of the spawn
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clip, player.position + unitSpawnDirection, explosionDistanceVolumen);
}
```

Use:

```
PlaySound(clip, collision.transform, Camera.main.transform, DistanceSoundLimit);
```